# Can domain-driven-design read model have basic logic?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I have a question regarding `read models`. I use read models when i get data from database and eqivalent entity/aggregate models to use in repositories. My question is can `read model` class have `constructor` which would check `properties`? For instance could I have such `read model class`. From the other hand i already have such checks in eqivalent domain model `EmployeeModel` therefore i am not convinced as it would be a bit of duplication. The additional question would be if in my EmployeeModel (domain) has not nullable EmploymentDate can i mark it nullablein read model means can read model be a diffrent that eqivalent `domain model`?

```
class EmployeeReadModel
{
     public DateTime? EmploymentDate { get; set; }
}
```

can i add constructor and check for such read model?

```
class EmployeeReadModel
{
     public DateTime? EmploymentDate { get; set; }

     EmployeeReadModel(DateTime? employeeDate)
     {
           EmploymentDate = employeeDate?? throw new Exception();
     }
}
```

Comment: What is your actual question? It isn't fully clear

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski i've edited post

Comment: Well, it depends on your needs and current architecture. This kind of questions is off-topic and opinion-based

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski i use read models in Query namespace(infrastructure layer) so when i get some data from database i filll out read model and send to higher layers ( presenters ). Also from presenters i pass specification class containing read model to query namespace with fields to filter in WHERE clause

Comment: the best would be that read model class could inherit somehow fields checks from eqivalent domain model class

Answer (score 1):

A *read model* is something that I see as going over-the-wire.  As such it should be easily serializable and methods usually present a problem.  Also, if there isn't a default constructor then you also have issues.

Since a read model represents existing data there isn't too much sense in validating it.  I would rather leave the validation to the domain model.

Given that a read model is more of a data transfer object chances are that once it leaves your system the receiving system is going to use it plainly as data.  For instance, even a web front-end would parse a json representation of the data to consume it.

If you really would like methods on your read model classes then perhaps consider extension methods as these don't interfere with any serialization.

Answer (score 1):

> Can domain-driven-design read model have basic logic?

You won't normally have domain logic, in the sense of "state machines" in the read model.

However, you do have constraints that you may need to satisfy, that are inconsistent with the data that you have available.

For example, suppose I'm sent a query with `ID:12345`, and I'm supposed to respond with a message using the `Foo` schema, which includes a Bar member that is restricted to the integer values 0-9.  We look in the book of record using `ID:12345`, and discover that the domain model has decided "this one goes to eleven".

So the data that is available doesn't match the required pre-conditions.  Now what?

One thing to notice in this sort of setting is that you've got conflicting requirements; if you manage to get all the way to production without discovering that conflict, then you've failed at a number of quality inspection points in your pipeline.

In other words, you're supposed to not have this problem by having discovered it and fixed it a long time ago.

One of the nice things about crash on conflict is that it pulls the Andon cord hard -- everything screeches to a halt.  Bonus - that's really easy to detect.  The downside, of course, is that you lose revenue until you get a fix deployed.

The downside is that a lot of things can get caught in the blast radius of the crash.  And in particular if your monitoring and repairing tools can't run because you are crashing on conflict, it's going to be a real pain to fix.

In other words, we want to be very precise - it's not the responsibility of the read model to detect whether the write model or the human operators are behaving correctly; it's only the job of the read model to determine if read model can satisfy its own requirements with the data that has been provided.